# How can I swap the diff panes in the changes view in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I view my current changes in VS Code the HEAD is on the left and the local (editable) version is on the right. Is there a way to swap these panes so the local version is on the left?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77638341/836330 for how to swap the diff editors left and right via a built-in command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently (version 1.5.3) not possible to swap the panes in the diff view. You can create a feature request for this topic on [VSCode's GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Answer (score 6):

Use [SwapDiff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shalimski.swapdiff) VS Code Extension.