# Is there a way to switch the compare direction with VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comparison

I use VSCode as my default tool to compare files (git changes and others) and I sometimes I need to see the differences in the other way than I have them opened in the viewer.

For example, suppose I have the following comparison

[image]

And I want them to be shown the other way around like Doc2 <-> Doc1

[image]

Is there a way to easily do this without closing the current comparison and opening a new one in the other order?

Anything would work, it can be a shortcut (the ideal option) or a button that I can press which I am currently missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is supported in VS Code 1.86. You can use `Compare: Swap Left and Right Editor Side` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

If you want to bind it to a keyboard shortcut, the command's ID is `workbench.action.compareEditor.swapSides`. See also the `isInDiffEditor` [context key](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts).

If you're interested in the history, see [Allow to swap left and right hand side in diff editor
#20958](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20958).

Answer (score 13):

You currently can't do this (version 1.54), but it has been suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20958) on the github.

There is an extension for this [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shalimski.swapdiff).

Comment: It is not what I wanted to find out, but it is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the answer, hope it gets implemented soon

Answer (score 7):

There is no option yet to swap files but for other readers it would be helpful to know that the order in which you selected the files in the Explorer matters.

Lets say there are 2 files "file1" and "file2"

If you select file1 first and then file2 and then right click -> compare selected then file1 is on the left and file2 is on the right.

If you select file2 first and then file1 and then right click -> compare selected then file2 is on the left and file1 is on the right.

Comment: Too bad there isn't something as simple as that built it. But, this answer helps me know that order of file selection (click) matters

Comment: This stopped working at some point, for instance in version: 1.84.0 it no longer works